# Creating a scope to compare 2 dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql

I have a model called Feed that records two timestamps, Last_visited and Last_modified.

I'd like to render a list of feeds where last_modified > last_visited

I currently have this scope in my model:

```
scope :hottest, lambda {where("'last_modified' > ?", 'last_visited')}
```

Controller

```
def home
  @user = current_user
  @feeds = @user.feeds
end
```

And I'm rendering the links in the View like so:

```
%ol
  - @feeds.hottest.each do |feed|
    %li
      = render :partial => 'feeds/feed_link'
```

Here's what my server log renders (I'm using Postgres):

```
Feed Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "feeds".* FROM "feeds" WHERE "feeds"."user_id" = 1 AND ('last_modified' > 'last_visited')
```

I have one entry in the database where last_modified > last_visited, yet it does not render in my view as expected:

```
Foofeed
Last Modified 2013-06-15 01:08:27 UTC
Last Visited 2013-06-15 01:05:32 UTC
```

I'm a little puzzled as to why this doesn't work.

Any insight or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `scope :hottest, lambda {where("'last_modified' > ?", last_visited)}`

Comment: That gives me this NameError `undefined local variable or method 'last_visited' for #<Class:0x007fb4450f1788>`

Comment: Mind to show your `last_visited` declaration? From your server log I can see that you're comparing last_modified with last_visited (which is a string instead of date). You need to make sure that you are calling last_visited correctly. Try `self.last_visited`

Comment: Nope, still no luck. I'm wondering if this is the right approach? Would opening it into a class be more effective?

Comment: Sorry I think I've misunderstood your question. @trushkevich was right, just do `scope :hottest, lambda {where("last_modified > last_visited")}` then you should get what you wanted.

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. From server log: Feed Load (0.4ms) SELECT "feeds".* FROM "feeds" WHERE "feeds"."user_id" = 1 AND (last_modified > last_visited)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
scope :hottest, lambda {where("last_modified > last_visited")}
```

Here is an example for my model `User`:

```
scope :updated, lambda { where("updated_at > created_at").limit(1) }
scope :not_updated, lambda { where("updated_at = created_at").limit(1) }
```

in console:

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > User.updated
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (updated_at > created_at) LIMIT 1
 => [#<User id: 7, first_name: "Test1", last_name: "Test1", created_at: "2013-05-21 21:29:54", updated_at: "2013-06-15 00:09:12">]
1.9.3p194 :005 > User.not_updated
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (updated_at = created_at) LIMIT 1
 => [#<User id: 14, first_name: "Test2", last_name: "Test2", created_at: "2013-05-22 20:07:27", updated_at: "2013-05-22 20:07:27">]
```

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid. From server log: 

`Feed Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "feeds".* FROM "feeds" WHERE "feeds"."user_id" = 1 AND (last_modified > last_visited)`

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of how it works for me (also notice that I don't have `created_at` and `updated_at` among `attr_accessible`s). If it doesn't work for you, then I can't help you more, sorry.